# program doesn't remember value/can't return value (XCode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, random, return

Hi I have a little a problem. My program doesn't remember random value which is generated by clicking first button. But I want use that value in another button and there is the problem. If I try to return that value, program says that this methond shouldn't return value. Here's how my code looks like:

```
int randomprocess;
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
randomprocess = rand() % 3;
// Do something    }
- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender {
if (randomprocess == 0) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

If I won't write that very first line, the second button won't recognize 'randomprocess'. And now when I declare it it's still zero or whatever number I set it to equal.

Comment: Do you invoke `button:` first and after that `b1:`? Also it is a good thing to initialize your variables when you declare them.

Comment: If you copied and pasted directly from your source, your mistake is a spelling mistake in the variable when youre assigning a value to it, randomproces = rand() % 3; Should be randomprocess I imagine?

Comment: @Anrei0427 No no that spelling mistake is just here, I'm sorry. I'll fix it in a second.

Comment: @Alexander I don't know what you meen. HOw should I initialize mt variables?

Comment: @Alexander Yes I did that and it remembered always that number I initialized first. Problem is that I need that random value to remember, not that first one.

Comment: @Alexander Yes you're right. Button is first and then is b1 invoked.

Comment: Check the value of `randomprocess` in `button:`, the random function might return 0.

Comment: @Alexander I did the same. I made both button to write down value they got. 'Button' gave me random number and 'b1' gave me still zero. or any other number I set in the initialiation in the first line.

Comment: Did you declare by any chance a property with the very same name (`randomprocess`)?

Comment: Yes I check It hundred times :/

Comment: This is C? Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes it is C and it's in tags.

Comment: @Matthias what do you meen? I should declare by different name? How then I can use that random value in next piece of program?

Comment: @TomasJ, so perhaps you should first start to document yourself on the language that you are using. This is definitively not C. I suspect that this is Objective C?

Comment: @JensGustedt Oh my bed, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you have declared an iVar / property with the very same name, that covers your global variable. Use only a global variable **or** an iVar.

An declaration `int randomprocess;` outside a method or object head makes it to a 'normal' global C variable.

An iVar is a **local** variable in relation to your object. An property is (usually) an iVar with certain accessors.
If you have declared both, a global variable and a local one (resp, an iVar), the global one is not visible, but covered by the local one.

In general it is a bad idea to use global variables. If you have to, make it static. Better is to use an iVar.

**EDIT**
To make an property, your header should look like:

```
@interface myclass
@property (nonatomic,assign) int randomprocess;
// ...
@end
```

And for the implementation:

```
@implementation myclass
@synthesize randomprocess; // only for XCode < 4.4 needed
// ...

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
   self.randomprocess = rand() % 3;
 // Do something    
 }
- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender {
   if (self.randomprocess == 0) {
    // Do something
   } else {
    // Do something else
   }
 //
 }
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You're right. But how then I can use or return value from first button and use it in second button when I can't give them same name?

Comment: When I remove that global variable, my second button doesn't know what's `randomprocess`. And when I try to return it, program says that a void method shouldn't return value.

Answer (score 1):

Or you should just declare your variable like this

```
@interface myclass {
 int randomprocess;
}
```

inside .h file or :

```
@implementation myclass {
 int randomprocess;
}
```

inside .m file

This will declare internal variable (iVar) without property

If you will do this inside .m file (2nd sample) this variable will available only in current file

If you will do this inside .h file (1st sample) this variable will be available for current .m and in subclasses as well